# Box-api. What is the use of shared-link structure in File object

Tags: json, api, box-api

What is the use of shared-link structure in File object?

```
"shared_link": {
    "url": "https://www.box.com/s/rh935iit6ewrmw0unyul",
    "download_url": "https://www.box.com/shared/static/rh935iit6ewrmw0unyul.jpeg",
    "vanity_url": null,
    "is_password_enabled": false,
    "unshared_at": null,
    "download_count": 0,
    "preview_count": 0,
    "access": "open",
    "permissions": {
        "can_download": true,
        "can_preview": true
    }
}
```

I want to understand what are **url** and **download_url** fields, when I try to GET them I get 404 and 403 respectively.
How can I use **download_url** and **url** ?

Thank you

Comment: Hi xchg.ca, just checking in -- do you need any more help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Shared links serve two purposes:

First, you can browse to the URL and access the content if the permissions are set up to allow that.  (I couldn't browse to the ones you provided, so I'm assuming it's been disabled?)

Second, you can access resources not available to your current access token via the API.  I have a file with id `3954425794` and a shared link url  `https://www.box.com/s/amilne3xg32auzk9vqga`. With the `/shared_items` endpoint ([documentation](http://developers.box.com/docs/#shared-items-get-a-shared-item)) and that shared link, you can access information about that file.

> Request:
>
> ```
> curl https://api.box.com/2.0/shared_items
> -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_CODE"
> -H "BoxApi: shared_link=https://www.box.com/s/amilne3xg32auzk9vqga"
> ```
>
> Response:
>
> ```
> { "type":"file", "id":"3954425794", "name":"shared file.txt" }
> ```

If you were to attempt to access this file using the normal `GET /files/{id}` method, it would fail with a 404:

> Request:
>
> ```
> curl https://api.box.com/2.0/files/3954425794
> -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_CODE"
> ```
>
> Response:
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
> ```

Comment: Example I've provided is copied from box.com documentation :)

So I've made changes to permission of my files to "open", now when I use url from 'shared' object I can browse it/

Comment: What is the use of 'download_url' field ?

Comment: I believe `url` points to a preview of the file on Box.com, while `download_url` points to the file data itself.

Comment: Thank you John, I got it, this has to be direct link, but apparently is is only allowed for paid accounts. Is there anyway I can test it ?

Comment: What do you want to test, exactly?